# Is it possible to get pages from remote file system with next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, azure-blob-storage, server-side-rendering

Hi I am quite new to advance frontend technologies and I have simple question.

**scenario**

I would like to use *next.js* and its feature: server side rendering.
I would like also to have my js, css and html files stored in outside of host machine where next.js is running. I want to have my files in *azure blob storage*. It is neccessary because I would like to have many SPA pages and single wwwroot directory is not enough for me.

**Problem**

By default next.js get its files from `pages` directory at host machine.
Is it possible to tell *next.js* to get files from other file system etc. In this scenario it would be *azure storage*. I could not find any example or extension point to do that.

Comment: Technically, you only define your page structure in `pages` directory. After build, Next.js serves the static JS and CSS from `.next/static/` folder. Contents of which can be moved to a storage uploaded as `_next/static/`. More details here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/cdn-support-with-asset-prefix

Comment: No it is just quote. I still need to know how to map files from azure storage to next server